# Service starts again when I close app

Tags: android

I am feeling strange behaviour with service when i close my app or my app is destoyed. Service starts from beggining means onStartCommand() method calls again. If service runs in background it should not be called again please help me why its happening
This is my service code

```
package gcmtutorial.androidbegin.com.socket;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by shuser on 21-07-2016.
 */
public class Services extends Service {

    public static boolean status;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public class Hello implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            synchronized (this){
                int i=0;
                while (i<100){
                    try {
                        wait(1000);
                        Log.e("Status:", "value "+i);
                        i++;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            stopSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        status = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Hello());
        thread.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        status = false;
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("Status:","Service Destroyed");
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Services.class);
        if (Services.status == true) {
            Log.e("Check:","Service is Running");
        }else {
            Log.e("Check:","Service Will run now");
            startService(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me why such thing is happening with service. I get Toast as well Service Started and LogCat also shows value from 0

Comment: your `if condition` is reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

Per [START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY):

> **if this service's process is killed while it is started** (after returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the started state but don't retain this delivered intent. **Later the system will try to re-create the service.** Because it is in the started state, it will guarantee to call onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) after creating the new service instance;

If you'd like your Service to not automatically restart when your process is destroyed, return [START_NOT_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY)